# Magento add CDN on local server

Tags: performance, cdn

I want to create a new subdomain `cdn.domain.com` and serve all `media/js/css` trough that subdomain, to speed up total page load.
But therefore I want to create a new cdn folder, outside my current root folder.

Is that possible and is it enough to change the `system/configuration/general/web/unsecure` and `system/configuration/general/web/secure` to `cdn.domain.com`?

I mean are all new images than saved to the right folder directly or do I need to change other things as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll have to change other things as well. Magento does not have a CDN application built-in, so the CDN would have to be set up with another application. You could use Apache Vhosts for this to do it on the same server.

Changing those system configuration paths will have drastic consequences to your store. Cookies will break, your admin panel will have issues, etc. However, if you change the base skin url, base JS url, and base media url, to match your CDN, that should be fine.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for your info. So your advise will be, to keep it the default way? So don't change the base js and media url?

Comment: Well, you can change them when you have a CDN configured...

Comment: But, @HenkZ, it won't work well unless you configure a CDN. Glad it helped! Would you be willing to upvote and/or accept?

Comment: So when setting Apache Vhosts and then changing the base URL's should do the trick?

Comment: why do you need another media folder?? you just create a subdomain and point it to your root folder as main domain.

Comment: @MagenX that should be fine. Henkz see the above comment. My concern is with ensuring that OP knows that just changing them without setting up the "CDN"/subdomain doesn't do anything.